# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factor_analyzer' - Python Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import this module "FactorAnalyzer" for EFA (Exploratory Factor Analysis) using the code in a Notebook session (IBM Watson Studio Notebook):

```py
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
```

And I am getting the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factor_analyzer'

If it was occurring in my localhost, I probably would solve it by just typing `pip install factor_analyzer` in the terminal.

But I see no terminal in the Notebook and don't know how to proceed.

[image: notebook]

[image: error and code]

Hope my question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with the IBM Watson environment, but installing packages is probably specific to that service. Here is a post where they seem to discuss a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524334/watson-studio-importerror-no-module-named-pydotplus/55534989#55534989

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `!pip install factor_analyzer` before importing the same. Then notebook will install it if it is available in pip package.

PS: I wrote this because you said if, in the terminal, you would have done `pip install factor_analyzer` to solve this

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks =D